# Why converting an integer to truthy value works differently when using comparison operator vs using !! in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

Why this returns false

```
2 == true
```

While this return true

```
!!2
```

I couldn't find a proper explanation. I was surprised cause I thought both behave the same.

Comment: In JavaScript type conversion, only `1` evaluates to true `1 == true` while the rest of the integers evaluates to false. What is the difference between `==` and `!!` ? They are both converting type right?

Comment: "What is the difference between == and !!" --- that's a really wrong question. They are not comparable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `==` operator [first converts its operands to the same type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/?bcsi_scan_f2e829812cac6d67=0#sec-11.9.3) (if they're not already), and then compares the resulting values. In the case of `2 == true`, it converts `true` to be a number, which results in the value `1`. And of course `2 == 1` is `false`.

There is no `!!` operator, that is just the `!` operator used twice in a row. So `!!2` is actually doing `!(!2)`, i.e., it first evaluates `!2` to get `false`, and then evaluates `!false`, resulting in `true`. In other words, using `!!` converts any truthy value to be the actual boolean value `true`.

Note that all non-zero numbers are "truthy", so `!anyNumberButZero` will be `false`. (`NaN` is a special case: `!NaN` is `true`.)

Comment: I think my problem was: 1- Not understanding that true is evaluated to 1 in comparison. 2- Misunderstanding that only the integer 1 is the truthy value while the rest of the number are falsey.

Answer (score 1):

In case 1, When you do `2 == true` it tries to convert the checks for the value 2 equals to true or not. Hence the false. This applies only for the values above 1.

From docs of [==](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

> If one of the operands is Boolean, the Boolean operand is converted to 1 if it is true and +0 if it is false.

Since you comparing 2 against boolean true, and true converts to 1. Hence  `2==1` resolved to false.

However when you do `if(2)` checks if it is truthy or not. Since it is trurthy, you did !! becomes truthy again.

Examples of [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values in JavaScript (which will translate to true and thus execute the if block):

```
if (true)
if ({})
if ([])
if (42) . // your case
```

Comment: `==` does do some type coercion. `1 == true` evaluates as `true`.

Comment: "it checks for the value 2 equals to true or not. Hence the false." --- this is not entirely true.

Comment: @nnnnnn Isn't it the case only for 1 ?

Comment: @zerkms Isn't it the case only for 1 ?

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ it is, but your explanation of how and why it works is not correct.

Comment: edited a bit, let me know if I am still missing something here. Will delete.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I think you it make sense now

Comment: "it tries to convert the checks for the value 2 equals to true or not. Hence the false. This applies only for the values above 1." --- this whole thing should be rephrased.

Comment: @zerkms Please feel free to edit it, if you think my phrasing is wrong.

Comment: @zerkms I'm glad that OP got clarification from my answer. Have a good rest of the day.